# Is it possible to export an orgmode headline to orgmode format?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I keep notes in orgmode and a GitHub repository can display formatted orgmode.  I currently copy a headline to a new orgmode file to 'export' my text for publication on GitHub.  However, this differs from exporting to other formats in at least two important aspects:

1. The outermost headline is often a secondary headline in the 'export';
2. The :(no)export: tags are not respected, and I need to trace them manually and edit the file.

Hence my question: is it possible to export orgmode to orgmode?  I'm hoping for a solution not involving pandoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can export to org. This is described in the [org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Org-Export.html) chapter on exporting. You will need to enable the org export backend, via `M-x customize-variable org-export-backends`. Tick the box for `org` and save your settings.

Comment: I feel like an idiot for missing that (and not all the others (well, except man and texinfo)).  I added `(require 'ox-org)` to my init.el and it does exactly what I hoped for.  Thanks for pointing this out!